# A function using data.table for fast calculation of means

Tags: r, function, data.table

I created a function using data.table for fast calculation of means. It works well within the script, but it does not work after I installed it in the library. The error message is: `"Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list'"`. Thanks in advance for the help.

```
fastMean <- function(x,byCols=c('id')){
  library(data.table)
  dt = data.table(x)
  msf=dt[, lapply(.SD, mean),by=byCols]
  return(msf)
}
mean <- fastMean(iris,byCols=c('Species'))
```

Comment: You could import ‘subset.data.table’ to your library build.

Comment: Your code doesn't error for me; what versions are you running? Try re-starting your Rsession and don't load any other libraries, then run this code to see what it gives you.

Comment: R version: 3.4.3; data.table version: 1.10.4.3. Restarted R session, still not working.

Comment: package ‘subset.data.table’ is not available (for R version 3.4.3)

Comment: did you add data.table as a dependency to your DESCRIPTION file? You also don't need to `library(data.table)` in such case. Also, you could just make it a one-liner as in `data.table(x)[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = byCols]` (no need in `return` neither).

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you very much, David!